# How to handle bad requests in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, bad-request

I am using asp.net 3.5, there are some requests with special characters (for example `./` and `<`) return "bad request" by asp.net application, it looks like the `Application_Error` method in `Global.asax.cs` cannot handle these errors, are there any other methods to handle these request errors?

---

Requests examples:

http://localhost/abc./abc.aspx

http://localhost/ab<c.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being caused because the characters specified can cause security issues. [Further information](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/23/understanding-400-bad-request-exception.aspx).

Take a look at [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client) for how to handle these

Comment: Hi Smirkin, after i upgrade to asp.net 4, I can catch the error for http://localhost/ab<c.aspx, but i still cannot catch the error for http://localhost/abc./abc.aspx, it shows a 404 error. I try to set the customErrors in web.config, but it still does not work.
<customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="On"><error statusCode="404" redirect="Error.htm"/></customErrors>